# Is there a way to limit the keys returned on an object in a query?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a user object with dozens of keys on it. Is it possible to give a query some parameters such that only certain fields on the user come back and I have to fetch the rest?

Answer (score 1):

To limit the keys in the returned result set you can use 'keys' parameter in rest api.

Sample GET request: 
https://demodomain/parse/classes/ClassName?keys=key1,key2,key3

For more: 
https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#query-constraints